# Align items left in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a question about aligning items in HTML and CSS. I have a price and those prices must be aligned left, but as you can see these items are aligned left but the 4 must be 0 of the 80. These are prices and I think this is not very nice.

One thing I forgot to mention is that these prices are not manually added prices. These are generated with an API. So in the solution you gave me, you can split the number and the decimal. In this case it is one number. Maybe there is a way to split the number and to solve it this way, but I hope there is a better solution. Also I give you a better view of the table. The only thing that must aligned better is the right table row not the left one. As you can see in the picture.

EDIT:
Code: This is the HTML code and I am also using AngularJS

```
 <td md-cell class="tableWidthSell tableBorderLeft tableInnerCell">
                    <table md-table class="innerTable">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr md-row class="datatableRow" ng-repeat="order in term.timeblocks.INTRADAY.SELL | orderBy: 'price': true">
                                <td flex="100" class="tablePaddingLeft clickable" ng-click="openOrder($event, order)" ng-class="{tableMyOrder: order.mine}">{{order.price|number:2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!--Price data | Sell -->
                <td md-cell class="tableWidthSell tableInnerCell">
                    <table md-table class="innerTable">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr md-row class="datatableRow" ng-repeat="order in term.timeblocks.INTRADAY.SELL | orderBy : 'price' : true ">
                                <td flex="100" class="tablePaddingLeft clickable" ng-click="openOrder($event, order)" ng-class="{tableMyOrder: order.mine}">&nbsp;{{order.quantity|number:1}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

I hope someone can still help me.

[image: Full image]

Comment: put your code please.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Are you using Angular Material

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Yes I am using Angular Material

Comment: The does my below answer help? they're attributes you add to the element

Answer (score 0):

Similar discussion is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363239/aligning-decimal-points-in-html).

One solution would be to...

Just set all the numbers to have a predefined decimal precision. Say you want a 2 digit precision so you will format all your numbers to have two digits after the decimal point.

So for a number like `3218.66` it will be displayed like as such. And for a number like `350` it will be displayed as `350.00`.

So Now all you need to do is decide the precision and then right align all of them.

And as you said, later don the line you can use a container `<span>` or a `<div>` with a class, to align then right.

**[Example](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/BLQBLq)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular Material you can do

```
layout="row" layout-align="start"
```

Looks like you might be, but without more code it's difficult to know

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. Do you need more code to solve this problem? Please let me know.