# List Alignment with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list that displays numbers with decimals. I want them all aligned in the center but they have different decimal lengths so it's kinda causing some UI issues.

Example its current displaying something like

```
 14.88
18.123
20.452
 10.22
  3.1
```

Its current HTML & CSS is simply

```css
.my-list {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li>14.88</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone show me how to update my CSS so it displays something like this

```
14.88
18.123
20.452
etc
```

In short I want the list  to be aligned on the center, but I want the list items to be aligned on the left.

Comment: can you provide your code ( html , css)..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning decimal points in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363239/aligning-decimal-points-in-html)

Comment: I feel like using JS to align a simple list is overkill

Comment: "I want them to align in the center but at the same time snap to the left most part." This makes no sense, unless you want the list to be centered with the list items aligned left.

Comment: @JonP Yes I want the list to be on the center, but the items to be aligned left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the list itself centered with the items left aligned:

**Option 1:** Using the list as a block but a fixed width

```css
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color:#ccc;
  width: 25%;
  /*Centers the list*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Not required in my example, but you may need it*/
li
{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li>14.88</li>
    <li>18.123</li>
    <li>20.452</li>
    <li>10.22</li>
    <li>3.1</li>
  </ul>
```

**Option 2:** Wrap the list in a `div` and set the list to `inline-block`

```css
div {
  /*Centers this list*/
  text-align: center
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  /*Left align contents of list*/
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>14.88</li>
    <li>18.123</li>
    <li>20.452</li>
    <li>10.22</li>
    <li>3.1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See this article for more centering options:  https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You are using text-align:center.

Try the same with:

```
.my-list {
  text-align: left
}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try list-style css property for the same, to remove the bullets

```
.myList{
  text-align:left;
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes but if I do a left align everything will move to the left most part... I want them to stay in the Center but just the numbers properly aligned

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mylist{
list-style:none;
width:100px;
}
.mylist li{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul class="mylist">
  <li>14.88</li>
  <li>18.123</li>
  <li>20.452</li>
  <li>10.22</li>
  <li>3.1</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```